# Callback without ajax or iframe (Pure Code)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a conditional function in my controller for what it has been posted from the view. Therefore, I want to send the respond or a callback to the view when the data is submitted.

For some reason, I don't want to use ajax or iframe to handle this callback.

I am expecting a pure javascript combined with php to do this:

The sketch might be like this:

```
<script>
    var callbackFromController = <?php echo $callbackFromController;?>

    if(callbackFromController == "Love")
        {
            alert("This is Love"); 
        }
    else if(callbackFromController == "Wealth")
        {
            alert("This is Wealth"); 
        }
    else if(callbackFromController == "Healt")
        {
            alert("This is Healt"); 
        }
    else 
        {
            alert("This is Life"); 
        }

</script>
```

But I want to get the $callbackFromController as soon as the button is submitted (Like ajax success respond)

Once again, I don't want to use ajax or iframe for this one.

The reason I don't want to use ajax is I don't want to pass the url as well as the data in the ajax post.

**[Updated]**

Based on the answer I've got from this question, it is said that I have to use either ajax or iframe.

If I have to use ajax, can I do this without passing the url and/or data post or get?

Comment: If you don't want to do what's dynamic you have to do the only option left, reload the page on an interval.

Comment: I am very sure there is a way to achieve this, I need a help to think about that.

Comment: "I don't want to pass the url as well as the data in the ajax post" --- so you want the data to be sent without sending it?

Comment: You need to explain the original intention behind that. "I don't want" is not a technical explanation. If the reason is "to hide" something from someone - it's not possible for JS.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I want to hide this, another reason may because I have had already ajax script here for another functions (which I can't explain it one by one). That is why I only want to do different thing; this with php and alert it with js.

Answer (score 2):

PHP writes the value out *before* the page is served to the browser.

If that's the case, then PHP can not write it out *after* a button has been clicked on the page, unless you are reloading the page.

...an alternative might be to dynamically create a link to a new script page (which is actually a .php page, but served with an application/javascript MIME type), which contains both your script logic and your PHP writing...

This is a horrible solution, but it's technically possible; you just have to do the wrong thing at every level (client, apache web-server and php web-app) layer.

Comment: Thanks for the sketch. I hope it can be as simple as I expected. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to interact with PHP without reloading the page or using AJAX request or iframe, as you suggested.